# Setting NTFS Rights using powershell

Tags: powershell

Im trying to create a script to set specific (advanced)access rights to a folder. However i keep running into the same error. And i cannot seem to figure it out, im hoping you guys have a solution for me.
This is the error i get:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "FileSystemAccessRule" and the argument count: "5". At line:14 char:17
```

And this is the powershell code that i have:

```
$folder = "\\netwerk\data\tablet\Test2"
$ReadGroup = "netwerk\ACR_Test2_R"
$WriteGroup = "netwerk\ACR_Test2_RW"
$acl = Get-Acl $folder

$ReadallowString = 'ExecuteFile','ListDirectory','Read','ReadData','ReadAndExecute','ReadExtendedAttributes','ReadPermissions'
$WriteallowString = 'AppendData','CreateDirectories','CreateFiles','DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles','ExecuteFile','ListDirectory','Modify','Read','ReadAndExecute','ReadExtendedAttributes','ReadPermissions','Traverse','Write','WriteAttributes','WriteData','WriteExtendedAttributes'
$ReaddenyString = 'Delete','TakeOwnership','ChangePermissions'
$WritedenyString = 'Delete','TakeOwnership','ChangePermissions'

$AllowVar =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 
$DenyVar =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Deny

$AceAllowRead = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($ReadGroup, $ReadallowString, $inherit, $propagation, $AllowVar)
$AceAllowWrite = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($WriteGroup, $WriteallowString, $inherit, $propagation, $AllowVar)
$AceDenyRead = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($ReadGroup, $ReaddenyString, $inherit, $propagation, $DenyVar)
$AceDenyWrite = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($WriteGroup, $WritedenyString, $inherit, $propagation, $DenyVar)

$inherit = [system.security.accesscontrol.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$propagation = [system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None"

$acl.AddAccessRule($AceAllowRead)
$acl.AddAccessRule($AceDenyRead)
$acl.AddAccessRule($AceAllowWrite)
$acl.AddAccessRule($AceDenyWrite)
Set-Acl $folder $acl
```

Seems like it trips at the part where i am Creating the FileSystemAccessRule's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is with the position of your variable  $inherit and $propagation in your script. They should be declared before that you call them.
Try this :

```
$folder = "\\netwerk\data\tablet\Test2"
$ReadGroup = "netwerk\ACR_Test2_R"
$WriteGroup = "netwerk\ACR_Test2_RW"
$acl = Get-Acl $folder

$ReadallowString = 'ExecuteFile','ListDirectory','Read','ReadData','ReadAndExecute','ReadExtendedAttributes','ReadPermissions'
$WriteallowString = 'AppendData','CreateDirectories','CreateFiles','DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles','ExecuteFile','ListDirectory','Modify','Read','ReadAndExecute','ReadExtendedAttributes','ReadPermissions','Traverse','Write','WriteAttributes','WriteData','WriteExtendedAttributes'
$ReaddenyString = 'Delete','TakeOwnership','ChangePermissions'
$WritedenyString = 'Delete','TakeOwnership','ChangePermissions'

$AllowVar =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 
$DenyVar =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Deny
$inherit = [system.security.accesscontrol.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$propagation = [system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None"

$AceAllowRead = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($ReadGroup, $ReadallowString, $inherit, $propagation, $AllowVar)
$AceAllowWrite = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($WriteGroup, $WriteallowString, $inherit, $propagation, $AllowVar)
$AceDenyRead = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($ReadGroup, $ReaddenyString, $inherit, $propagation, $DenyVar)
$AceDenyWrite = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($WriteGroup, $WritedenyString, $inherit, $propagation, $DenyVar)

$acl.AddAccessRule($AceAllowRead)
$acl.AddAccessRule($AceDenyRead)
$acl.AddAccessRule($AceAllowWrite)
$acl.AddAccessRule($AceDenyWrite)
Set-Acl $folder $acl
```

Comment: Yea this is indeed the problem... cant believe i've missed that have been looking at this for hours x.x